# raspberry pi counter won't stop counting

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, counter

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi project that ideally will count each time the beam break sensor I have is broken. I'm almost certain all the hardware is set up correctly.

What is currently happening with my code is that the counter ticks up when the beam isn't broken, and when the beam gets broken, the counter continues to count, but at a much faster rate. Does anyone know why the counter is counting even when the beam isn't broken?

(I'm not worried about debouncing as of now, I want to get the above problem figured out first)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

BeamBreak = 7
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(BeamBreak, GPIO.IN)

try:
    boxes = 0
    while boxes < 10000:
        if(GPIO.input(BeamBreak)==False):
            boxes = boxes + 1
            print(boxes)
        else:
            boxes = boxes
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: "why the counter is counting even when the beam isn't broken?" Because that's what this code is meant to be doing. `if(GPIO.input(BeamBreak)==False)` you increase `boxes` by 1 until it is equal to `10000`. Also, please prefer `if not GPIO.input(BeamBreak)`, it is much cleaner.

Comment: I cleaned it up like you told me. The code should be saying to only count (and stop at 10000) when the beam is broken (input from BeamBreak is False), so why is the counter going up when the beam isn't broken?

Comment: Almost certainly while the beam is apparently unbroken there are some very narrow pulses of "break" from it. When it counts while not broken, how fast does it tick up when "not broken"? Can you move your light source closer to the sensor, does that reduce the count rate when not broken? You may have to add that debounce (i.e. Filtering) that you were postponing, to ensure you don't count "break" periods narrower than a threshold.